# Core Data Deletion Unsuccessful *easy fix?*

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-data, nsmanagedobject, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I have a simple XCDataModel that contains one Entity with One Attribute. Essentially, I am saving a series of Dates.

Now, I Know I am adding the NSDates properly because I run a fetch request after adding them and run through the results like so:

```
for (NSManagedObject *info in fetchedObjects) {
    NSLog(@"Name: %@", [info valueForKey:@"attribute"]);
}
```

And every additional NSDate is accounted for. Example from Log:

```
2012-06-19 12:40:38.531 Arts Days[47194:16103] Name: 2013-03-27 04:00:00 +0000
2012-06-19 12:40:38.531 Arts Days[47194:16103] Name: 2013-03-01 05:00:00 +0000
2012-06-19 12:40:38.532 Arts Days[47194:16103] Name: 2013-01-01 05:00:00 +0000
```

**Now,** when I try to delete an object from Core Data, it proves unsuccessful (by running the same fetch and running through the results again).

Here is the fetch:

```
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Entity" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

[fetchRequest setFetchBatchSize:366];

NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"date" ascending:NO];
NSArray *sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:sortDescriptor, nil];

NSError *error = nil;

[fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

NSArray *fetchedObjects = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];

for (NSManagedObject *object in fetchedObjects) {
    if ([[object valueForKey:@"date"] isEqualToDate:date]) {
        [managedObjectContext deleteObject:object];
    }
}
if (![managedObjectContext save:&error]) {
    NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
}
```

Also, the NSLog with Unresolved error contains nil nil...

Do you know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: If that is all your code, then you never actually performed the fetch with your `fetchRequest` and `fetchObjects` is empty (nil, really).

Comment: I left that line out by accident

Comment: have you debugged the code? is it executing as expected?

Comment: It builds with no errors or warnings. It executes not as expected, because the object just doesn't delete.

Comment: While it won't fix your issue, I would suggest using an NSPredicate to grab only the records with the date you wish to match, then iterate through that list of results to perform the delete, and finally do the save **after** finishing with the loop body.

Comment: I agree with @gschandler, there should probably be just one save after all deletes.

Comment: What does your model actually look like? Your first code snippet doesn't actually prove you have a correct date in the record, let alone any date. You are just printing the contents of `attribute` (which appears to be a name of some sort). Did you try logging the dates you have in each record to confirm valid data?

Comment: OK, I put the code beneath the loop. The error persists..

Comment: i wrote "attribute" as a generic name for the post.. I will include the logged text above.

Comment: I noticed everywhere else in the code you use `self.managedObjectContext`, except where you call `deleteObject` and `save:`. Could it be you are using a local instance that is not valid (nil)?

Comment: @gschandler that was it. Would you mind posting that in the answers section. Thanks! (I knew it would be small)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears you use two different `NSManageObjectContext` instances. `self.managedObjectContext` (an ivar) to set up your fetch request and perform the fetch, but a local instance to do the `deleteObject:` and `save:` operations. The local instance `managedObjectContext` is probably nil and not referring to the same object as the ivar.